# How do I get my channel recommendations back on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I remember to have had channel recommendations when I clicked on **Recommendations**.

http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy//http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/youtube-broadcast/topic2.jpg

But apparently I don't get to see these anymore, is there a way to get them back? Or third party?

<sub>I like unsigned singers and songwriters, I can't find them since they removed them from the Music section and this problem...</sub>

Comment: Do you have an account and do you clear your cookies often?

Comment: @EightDays: Yes, I have an account. No, I have ran weeks to months without clearing them and I have the problem for quite some time now. I cleared everything in my browser this week but that's irrelevant to this...

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, there seems to be something up with the recommendations.
The new section: [Recommended Channels](http://www.youtube.com/my_subscriptions_recommendations) shows for my account,

> Sorry, there are no more recommendations available at this time. Try again later.

I have tried to subscribe to someone new to see if this changes anything but this just gives the

> Check out other channels user likes:

My suggestion for now is to utilize the recommended videos that shows on the home page until someone comes up with an answer/fix to this.

Comment: +1 for the confirmation, perhaps I should try to contact YouTube / Google to get this fixed if nobody comes up with a handy alternative. The recommended videos system works very bad for me and mostly results in the same videos or too similar videos, unless I spent quite some time in going through all the videos it suggests...